# Import file and submit when popup closes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to submit the file I am importing once I click OK on system's window for uploading files, but i don't know how to do it... This is what I've done so far:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" style="display:none" />

<button class="btn pull-right" ng-click="submitCashierFile()">Import</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submitCashierFile = function () {
        angular.element('#file-input').trigger('click');

// I should have something like this next i guess?

$scope.cashierfile.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: config.baseAddress + 'test/uploadCashierExcel',
                data: { file: $scope.cashierfile }
            });

            $scope.cashierfile.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.cashierfile.result = response.data;
                    toastService.success('You have added .xlsx');
                });
            }, function (response) {
                toastService.error(response);
           });

    };
```

So I triger the click, open the modal to choose file, the problem for me is how to submit it on clicking OK in that modal. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are okay with using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload), i would suggest to go with that. Its very simple to achieve what you want using this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, but I will give it a shot base on what I did understand.

You should map the control's onchange event. This will fire right after selecting the file to upload.
Then you should do the actual upload of the file.

When I need to do this task, I drop use of Angular and go for HTML5 file upload mechanism. That one is working as you describe...